# Could not load mock: class already exists when run with RefreshDatabase Trait

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, mockery

```php
public function testSomething()
{
    $this->login();

    m::mock('overload:MyClass', function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('METHOD')
            ->andReturn(
                (object)[
                    'status'  => true,
                    'message' => 'Message',
                ]
            );
    });

    $this->post(route('ROUTE'))
        ->assertRedirect()
        ->assertSessionHas(
            'success',
            'Message'
        );
}
```

When I try to run this with:

`use DatabaseTrasactions`: It works

`use RefreshDatabase`: It does NOT work

**Error:** `Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException : Could not load mock \MyClass, class already exists`

**Laravel**: 5.5
**PHPUnit**: 6.5.14

##### Tried

- @runTestsInSeparateProcesses (on entire class)
- @runInSeparateProcess (on single test)

Comment: what is the real name of the class you are trying to mock? Why `overload`?

Comment: Because I don't have the option to use interfaces to do dependency injection; have to provide mock for hard dependencies; dealing with legacy code: `App\Helpers\MyClass`

Comment: The documentation says: `(which is NOT currently loaded)`, so you cannot use `overload:MyClass`. could you show the code you are trying to mock? I never had to use `overload` specially with Laravel

Comment: I use overload all the time this is not the problem, you have very old version so maybe is already fixed. You test in memory database or reqular?